# Как вывести посты из инстаграмма в нескольких местах страницы

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-api

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var userFeed = new Instafeed({
   get: 'user',
   userId: '1805227844',
   clientId: 'e9f1aeae68ed43c18c4a96b64038e78f',
   accessToken: '1805227844.e9f1aea.68a3fe3edcf548c08cb46093cd4c966b',
   resolution: 'standard_resolution',
   template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" id="{{id}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
   sortBy: 'most-recent',
   limit: 6,
   links: false
 });
 userFeed.run();
</script>
```

Использую скрипт `instafeed.js`. Нужно вывести посты из инстаграмма в нескольких местах страницы. У меня не получается, так как скрипт запихивает их в блок с определенным айдишником.

Answer (score 1):

Да, есть такая возможность, делается с помощью цикла:

```
function getMultipleTags (tags) {
    var feeds = [];
    for (var i=0, len=tags.length; i < len; i++) {
        feeds.push(new Instafeed({
            // rest of your options
            get: 'tagged',
            tagName: tags[i],
            target: "instafeed-" + tags[i]
        }));
    }
    return feeds;
}

// получить несколько тегов
var myTags = getMultipleTags(['glass', 'wood', 'rock']);

// запустить каждый экземпляр
for(var i=0, len=myTags.length; i < len; i++) {
    myTags[i].run();
}
```

Ссылка на источник: [Is it possible to have the feed display more then one tag/user?](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/12). Смотрите ответ **stevenschobert** от 26 июня 2013. Вполне приемлимый код, который подходит для вашей задачи, просто нужно немного переделать.

Comment: пишет ошибку(  /**/ instafeedCachebc8e4b615c1a401b.parse({"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException", "error_message": "This request requires scope=public_content, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=public_content to be granted this permissions."}})

Comment: нужен scope=public_content, вроде как получил его, а ошибка не исчезает в консоли

Comment: @AntonMazhuto по этой ошибке вот ответ: [OAuthPermissionsException Instagram API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33876400/5275890)

Comment: не помогла статья( https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENTID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code&scope=SCOPE - по этой ссылке описанной в статье, переходит и выдается ошибка   {"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid Client ID"} - @Denis Bubnov